IDE warning when debugging

how to I turn off this warning, my code is still run this not in my breakpoint, I don't need to use this.
It so hard to find a KEY this problem to search it
Do you know anything more about debugging or tricks that experienced programmers use?

dont assign it to a variable, you never use it is what its telling you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Instead of turning it off, why don't you fix the issue it's telling you about? var block = you are assigning to block but never use it. so either remove var block = or use block later in your code.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Hints and warnings are there for a reason, which is to tell you there's an issue with your code. Instead of trying to hide them or turn them off, you should learn to read what they tell you and then FIX the issue. It not only prevents problems and bugs that are hard to track down, but it makes you a much better programmer.

@Minh Tuấn Bùi Hi Minh, The comments from the community members above are very reasonable, and I also suggest that you prioritize solving the problem in the code itself. But if you don't want to do that, then VS does provide some ways to shield the warning information as you wish. You can take a look at the answer in my post. :)

Since you never use the code, you can remove it if you don't need it.
or if you want to use it, please add additional code that using the variable block.
But if you really want to disable it, here has some ways:

In the Project Properties:

Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer and select "Properties."
Go to the "Build" tab.
In the "Suppress warnings" text box, enter the warning numbers you want to suppress, separated by semicolons (e.g., IDE0059).





In the Code File (C#):

You can suppress warnings directly in your code using the #pragma warning disable directive. Place this at the top of your C# file or before the relevant code section:
#pragma warning disable IDE0059 // Unnecessary assignment of a value
// Your code here
#pragma warning restore IDE0059 // Restore the warning after the necessary code






This is the official document:
Suppress a warning in file
